# Echoing a MySQL string with text, then style it with CSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, hidden

I've been looking on the internet for a while, to see how I can make up my echo'd string.
I have been able to make up alot of stuff with examples. But when it comes to my own code, I'm not able to this, even when I do EXACTLY the same stuff.

This is my echo'd PHP:

```
echo "<div id=\"suggestions\"><h1> Our suggestions for you: </h1>";
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($frequency))
{
$query = "SELECT country FROM project.countries WHERE countryID LIKE (".$row['countryID'].")";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$countrysuggestion = $row['country'];

echo "<h2>Suggestion no.".$i." is: ".$countrysuggestion."!</h2>";
$i = $i + 1;
}
echo "</div>";
```

Then this is our style CSS code:

```
<style type=”text/css”>
#suggestions{
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

On our website this echo'd "stuff" doesn't go to invisible. Can anyone help us out here?

Comment: are you sure that `mysqli` is fetching any data??

Comment: So it's echoing out the information but not applying the CSS class to `suggestions`?

Comment: have you tried display:none;

Comment: Ghost Echo: Yes, that's our problem!

Comment: NoobEditor: It does, because it is visible on the site

Comment: Pwner: the problem isn't in the CSS command, because nothing in the markup language works

Comment: I doubt it will make any difference whatsoever, but you've got funny quote characters in `type="text/css"`.

Comment: @wickywills It will make a difference. That is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming that below is your `inline-css`

```
<style type=”text/css”>
  #suggestions{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

change the `quotes` and `visibility: hidden;` to

```
     <style type="text/css"> /* <= notice quote in this line, these are 
apostrophes in yours, this makes a huge difference */
        #suggestions{
           display: none; /*notice none here*/
        }
      </style>
```

**Addition edit**

`visibility: hidden` hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.

`display: none` removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code.

Comment: is `visibility:none;` a  proper value?

Comment: @GhostEcho : perfect catch mate...that was my bad typo....added an edit in my answer after your comment..+1 to it :)

Comment: `visibility: none;` didn't work. Luckily, the mistake was in the quotes! Thanks alot. Now I can try to set it visible with jQuery!

Comment: @RichardDirven : `visibility: none;` was my bad typo...please see **Addition edit** part in my answer!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try writing inline `CSS` as below

```
echo "<div id='suggestions' style='visibility: hidden;'>
      <h1> Our suggestions for you: </h1>";
echo "</div>";
```

or change quotes in style tag

```
 <style type="text/css">
      #suggestions{
           visibility: hidden;
      }
 </style>
```